# Converting wav files into raw binary without header

Tags: matlab, binary, signal-processing, wav, converters

I am trying to convert wav files in a directory into 16khz, 2 channel, and signed int 16 and then into raw binary **without header information**, which means I cannot use audiowrite. I decided to write this MATLab script to do so. Is this correct? I feel I may have overlooked something. Thank you.

```
clc;clear all;close all
x=1;
while(x<=5)
chr = int2str(x)
FileName1=strcat('meow/',chr) %Loading File Name
FileName=strcat(FileName1,'.wav')
%Read the data to the MATLAB using audioread.
[y,fs] = audioread(FileName);
%change to 16000 sampling rate and sign16 stream
newfile = strcat('meow/',chr);
y = int16(y);
fs2=16000;
y1=[];
y1(:,1) =y(1:fs/fs2:end,1);
y1(:,2) =y(1:fs/fs2:end,2);

fid = fopen(FileName, 'r');
data = fread(fid, [2, Inf], 'int16');
fclose(fid);

data=y1';
bit1 = int16(rem(floor((1 ./ [128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1].') * double(data(1,:))), 2));
bit2 = int16(rem(floor((1 ./ [128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1].') * double(data(2,:))), 2));
%https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/386841-how-to-convert-wav-file-into-binary
bit = [bit1 bit2];
FileNameend = strcat(newfile,'.bin');
save(FileNameend, 'bit'); % save using .bin
f = fopen(FileNameend, 'w');
fwrite(f, bit, 'double');
filename=strcat(newfile,'x.wav');
delete(filename);
x=x+1;
end
```

Comment: Why do you think you might have overlooked something?

Comment: It looks a bit over-complicated to me. I would have thought you could just read using `audioread`, then write using `fwrite`. But if what you did works, then just use that.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion: use `audiowrite` to write a WAV, then use the [sox command line tool](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) to convert the WAV to a headerless raw binary file with:

```
sox in.wav out.raw
```

You could even call sox from Matlab through the [system](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) function.

Comment: Can I also convert with sox before converting wav to headerless binary file? For example:

sox 1.wav -b 16 -c 2 -r 16k -t raw 1.raw